# Can $y(x)=x^2$ be solution of an ODE with bounded coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose that $y(x)=x^2$ is a solution of $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$ on $(0,1)$ where $P,Q$ are continuous functions on $(0,1)$. Can both $P,Q$ be bounded functions? Justify.

I am trying to solve this problem. After putting $y=x^2$ in the equation , I got something but could not proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

You get $2+2x\,P(x)+x^2\,Q(x)=0$ for $x\in(0,1)$. This means that
$x\cdot (2\,P(x)+x\,Q(x))=-2$, so $$2P(x)+xQ(x)=-2/x.$$ Therefore, $2P(x)+xQ(x)$ is unbounded in $(0,1)$. This can only be true if $P(x)$ or $xQ(x)$ is unbounded, and if $xQ(x)$ is unbounded, so is $Q$.

So, $P$ and $Q$ cannot be bounded functions on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

substitute $y = x^2$ in the ode $y'' +P(x)y' +yQ(x) = 0$ we get
$$
2 +2P(x)x +Q(x)x^2 = 0 \\
$$
That means
\begin{align}
Q(x) &= -\frac{2}{x^2} -\frac{2P(x)}{x}&  P(x) = -\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{2}Q(x)x
\end{align}
so if $P(x)$ is bounded on $(0,1)$ then $Q(x)$ is not, and vice versa.